# Apache mod_wsgi better configuration

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am deploying my django-based web apps using apache mod_wsgi. This is my virtualhost:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:*>

    ServerAdmin my_email@emails.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/appWSGI/gestioner/gestioner/

    Alias /static /var/www/appWSGI/gestioner/static/

    <Directory /var/www/appWSGI/gestioner/>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                    Require all granted
            </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess gestioner python-path=/var/www/appWSGI/gestioner python-home=/var/www/appWSGI/env
    WSGIProcessGroup gestioner
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/appWSGI/gestioner/gestioner/wsgi.py
    WSGIPassAuthorization On
</VirtualHost>
```

This basic configuration is working fine. I would like to know if it is possible to improve this maybe there are other directives that i don't know about..
It is possible to have another configuration that boots performance ?

thank you all in advance!!

Comment: There are a whole bunch of options to ``WSGIDaemonProcess`` which can be set to help provide a system which can better deal with abnormal conditions. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H6Q3l11fjU0 As to improving performance, it is impossible to give guidance unless you have metrics available about how your application performs. How long requests take. Whether CPU or I/O bound and various other things.

Comment: Thank you so much for that source! Really useful!

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton After watching your video I see that I am lack of time-out's directives..

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
import sys   
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "your_project.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

If you are using python2

> sudo apt-get install python-pip apache2 libapache2-mod-wsgi

If your are using python3

> sudo apt-get install python3-pip apache2 libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3

Then Here goes the apache configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev.example.com #your server name
    ServerAlias dev.example.com #your server alias

    DocumentRoot #your document root
    WSGIProcessGroup dev.example.com
    WSGIPassAuthorization On
    WSGIDaemonProcess dev.example.com python-home=/home/robert/django/robertenv python-path=/home/robert/django/
    WSGIScriptAlias /backend /home/robert/django/project/wsgi.py process-group=dev.example.com

    Alias "/uploads" "/home/robert/django/uploads" #uploads directory

    <Directory #your document root>
            Require all granted

            RewriteEngine on
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
            RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

            RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/robert/django/uploads>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/robert/django/project>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                    Require all granted
            </Files>
    </Directory>
```

Source [apache2 wsgi con](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/) and [source1](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: How is that supposed to answer the question?

Comment: Sorry @Robert, couldn't get your answer!